# How to get image from gallery and pass it to another activity

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I'm making an app that will let the user get a picture using a camera or choose from the gallery and pass that image to another activity to be displayed. I got the camera part taken care but picking images from the gallery forced closed the app.

here is the piece of the code:
main:

```
 public void captureImage(View view) {
    Intent iCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(iCamera.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null){
        startActivityForResult(iCamera, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
public void galImage(View view) {
    Intent iGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    iGallery.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(iGallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Camera.class);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        intent.putExtra("Bitmap",bitmap);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        try{
            Bitmap bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Camera.class);
            intent2.putExtra("Bitmap",bitmap2);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Camera.java:

```
 public class Camera extends AppCompatActivity {

            Button btnCap, btnUse;
            ImageView imageView3;
            Uri imageUri;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

                btnCap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCap);
                btnUse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUse);
                imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

                //camera
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
                imageView3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
}
```

here is the error I got when I used an image from the gallery:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw//storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181117_043417.jpg typ=image/jpeg flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.janrex.readem/com.example.janrex.readem.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
```

Comment: instead of passing the file, try saving the photo as a file and pass the path of that file to the second activity

Comment: @NikosHidalgo How can I do that and should i do that for both gallery and camera?

Comment: How do you capture the image in the first place, can you add the code to your post?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I added the code for the camera and the gallery.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your original question.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Okay. But can you still help me with my question?

Comment: could you post the entire logcat? maybe I'll be able to figure it out if I see the entire log

Comment: also since the error happens when the user selects photos from the gallery, it would help to see the code where you handle the gallery pening and choosing of the photo. I'm not really sure why you're passing a view in your methods that create the intents to start the new activities yet you never use it.